# Measuring performance/throughput of fast code ignoring processor speed?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, assembly, cpu

Is there a way I could write a "tool" which could analyse the produced x86 assembly language from a C/C++ program and measure the performance in such a way, that it wouldnt matter if I ran it on a 1GHz or 3GHz processor?

I am thinking more along the lines of instruction throughput? How could I write such a tool? Would it be possible?

Comment: Well, if you only use relative measures then you can pick a single processor (ignoring processor differences) and run multiple versions. Once you use one of them as the base line, the rest of them would be independent of the actual speed at which the test run. Note: lots of handwaving in this comment!!!!

Comment: You could write a tool that analyzed the code from two versions of an algorithm and with some measure of certainty would be able to tell which one was going to be faster, but it is often impossible to make static predictions about things like data locality.

Comment: Not possible, too many x86 variants and even within a single chip there are too many other things going on to get a relevant answer.  The same code on the same machine can run wildly different speeds depending on compiler options and the operating system and other factors.  to write the tool you would need to have access to the chip internals as well as model the whole architecture of the motherboard and peripherals, it is far easier and cheaper just to buy a few different computers and take when you get when you benchmark it on hardware.

Comment: the processor itself is today only a small part of the performance equation.  processor speed vs the memory and other items plays a good sized role in the performance so 1ghz vs 3ghz isnt expected to be a linear difference for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to be equivalent to the halting problem, in which case it can't be done. Things such as branch prediction, memory accesses, and memory caching will all change performance irrespective of the speed of the CPU upon which the program is run.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could, but it would have very limited relevance. You can't tell the running time by just looking at the instructions.

- What about cache usage? A "longer" code can be more cache-friendly, and thus faster.
- Certain CPU instructions can be executed in parallel and out-of-order, but the final behaviour depends a lot on the hardware.

If you really want to try it, I would recommend writing a tool for valgrind. You would essentially run the program under a simulated environment, making sure you can replicate the behaviour of real-world CPUs (that's the challenging part).

EDIT: just to be clear, I'm assuming you want dynamic analysis, extracted from real inputs. IF you want static analysis you'll be in "undecidable land" as the other answer pointed out (you can't even detect if a given code loops forever).

EDIT 2: forgot to include the out-of-order case in the second point.

Comment: And instructions can get re-ordered, and pipelines on different CPUs can have different depths, and different load/store bypass behavior, and and and... Simply put, modern CPUs are modern.

Comment: @Nemo: indeed, I forgot to mention it in the second point, although that was what I had in mind. As Kamp said, if you think a CPU is just something that reads one instruction, executes it, then fetch the next instruction, you are doing it wrong ( http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1814327 ).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but only if the tool knows all the internals of the processor for which it is projecting performance.   Since knowing 'all' the internals is tantamount to building your own processor, you would correctly guess that this is not an easy task.  So instead, you'll need to make a lot of assumptions, and hope that they don't affect your answer too much.  Unfortunately, for anything longer than a few hundred instructions, these assumptions (for example, all memory reads are found in L1 data cache and have 4 cycle latency; all instructions are in L1 instruction cache but in trace cache thereafter) affect your answer a lot.  Clock speed is probably the easiest variable to handle, but the details for all the rest that differ greatly from processor to processor.

Current processors are "speculative", "superscalar", and "out-of-order".  Speculative means that they choose their code path before the correct choice is computed, and then go back and start over from the branch if their guess is wrong. Superscalar means that multiple instructions that don't depend on each other can sometimes be executed simultaneously -- but only in certain combinations.  Out-of-order means that there is a pool of instructions waiting to be executed, and the processor chooses when to execute them based on when their inputs are ready.

Making things even worse, instructions don't execute instantaneously, and the number of cycles they do take (and the resources they occupy during this time) vary also.  Accuracy of branch prediction is hard to predict, and it takes different numbers of cycles for processors to recover. Caches are different sizes, take different times to access, and have different algorithms for decided what to cache.  There simply is no meaningful concept of 'how fast assembly executes' without reference to the processor it is executing on.

This doesn't mean you can't reason about it, though.  And the more you can narrow down the processor you are targetting, and the more you constrain the code you are evaluating, the better you can predict how code will execute.  Agner Fog has a good mid-level introduction to the differences and similarities of the current generation of x86 processors:
http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf

Additionally, Intel offers for free a very useful (and surprisingly unknown) tool that answers a lot of these questions for recent generations of their processors.  If you are trying to measure the performance and interaction of a few dozen instructions in a tight loop, IACA may already do what you want.  There are all sorts of improvements that could be made to the interface and presentation of data, but it's definitely worth checking out before trying to write your own:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer

To my knowledge, there isn't an AMD equivalent, but if there is I'd love to hear about it.